# Linux kernel: dsi lvds bridge driver loading before panel driver is loaded

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm running linux on an IMX8MM which uses the nxp-imx version of the linux kernel.

https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/linux-imx/tree/?h=lf-5.15.y

The problem is that I'm trying to get the sn65dsi83.c dsi>lvds bridge driver to work. But there seems to be an issue with the order of driver loading.

From what I understand the chain looks like this: lcdif>mipi_dsi>sn65dsi83>panel

however to add the sn65dsi83 to the list of available bridges the panel needs to be loaded already, because if it isn't, the sn65dsi_probe()>sn65dsi83_parse_dt() function fails when it calls drm_of_find_panel_or_bridge() (It doesn't give any warnings that it has failed, it took me while to discover this with some added debug prints)

So the current order is: i2c devices get initialized among which the sn65dsi83, which fails.

then /driver/gpu/drm/imx/sec_mipi_dsim-imx.c which is an nxp kernel specific driver, tries to bind/attach the whole chain, which fails with code -517 (eprobe_defer) because the bridge wasn't initialised succesfully.

Then it initializes the panel-lvds.c driver.

Then because it fails with eprobe_defer it tries again a bit later and it all goes horribly wrong. But i think the main issue is this first load order of the drivers.

I've tried moving up the

obj-y           += panel/

line in /drivers/gpu/drm/Makefile, from what i've read this is what partially determines the load order. It has had some effect, the panel now loads before the kernel tries to bind the whole chain, but it is still after the loading of the i2c devices.

Though from what i have seen the order in every Makefile that i think affects this would load the panel before the i2c drivers.

I've also read about the init_module calls and the ordering that is used by them, but these modules are all called by probe functions and not regular init functions.

And if i trace back the module_i2c_driver(sn65dsi83_driver) and module_platform_driver(panel_lvds_driver) I can't seem to find any priority values for these init calls. So I think they have equal priority?

this is the current patch I use to raise the priority of the panel initialisation in my yocto meta-layer:

```
drivers/gpu/drm/Makefile | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/drivers/gpu/drm/Makefile b/drivers/gpu/drm/Makefile
index ad1112154898..26aa17580420 100644
--- a/drivers/gpu/drm/Makefile
+++ b/drivers/gpu/drm/Makefile
@@ -64,6 +64,7 @@ obj-$(CONFIG_DRM) += drm.o
 obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_MIPI_DBI) += drm_mipi_dbi.o
 obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_MIPI_DSI) += drm_mipi_dsi.o
 obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_PANEL_ORIENTATION_QUIRKS) += drm_panel_orientation_quirks.o
+obj-y          += panel/
 obj-y          += arm/
 obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_TTM)  += ttm/
 obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_SCHED)    += scheduler/
@@ -108,7 +109,6 @@ obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_INGENIC) += ingenic/
 obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_MEDIATEK) += mediatek/
 obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_MESON)    += meson/
 obj-y          += i2c/
-obj-y          += panel/
 obj-y          += bridge/
 obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_FSL_DCU) += fsl-dcu/
 obj-$(CONFIG_DRM_ETNAVIV) += etnaviv/
-- 
2.25.1
```

And here is the relevant part of the dmesg output:

```
[    0.336364] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: maps: function pinctrl group i2c4grp num 3
[    0.336373] pinctrl core: add 3 pinctrl maps
[    0.336389] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: maps: function pinctrl group i2c4-gpiogrp num 3
[    0.336397] pinctrl core: add 3 pinctrl maps
[    0.336419] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: found group selector 11 for i2c4grp
[    0.336469] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: found group selector 12 for i2c4-gpiogrp
[    0.336505] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: request pin 139 (MX8MM_IOMUXC_I2C4_SCL) for 30a50000.i2c
[    0.336513] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: request pin 140 (MX8MM_IOMUXC_I2C4_SDA) for 30a50000.i2c
[    0.336521] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: enable function pinctrl group i2c4grp
[    0.336528] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: write: offset 0x22c val 0x10
[    0.336535] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: write: offset 0x230 val 0x10
[    0.336543] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: pinconf set pin MX8MM_IOMUXC_I2C4_SCL
[    0.336549] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: write: offset 0x494 val 0x1d6
[    0.336557] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: pinconf set pin MX8MM_IOMUXC_I2C4_SDA
[    0.336563] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: write: offset 0x498 val 0x1d6
[    0.336730] imx-i2c 30a50000.i2c: obtain a copy of previously claimed pinctrl
[    0.336739] imx-i2c 30a50000.i2c: GPIO lookup for consumer sda
[    0.336746] imx-i2c 30a50000.i2c: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    0.336766] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'sda-gpios' property of node '/soc@0/bus@30800000/i2c@30a50000[0]' - status (0)
[    0.336839] gpio gpiochip4: Persistence not supported for GPIO 21
[    0.336849] imx-i2c 30a50000.i2c: GPIO lookup for consumer scl
[    0.336855] imx-i2c 30a50000.i2c: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    0.336871] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'scl-gpios' property of node '/soc@0/bus@30800000/i2c@30a50000[0]' - status (0)
[    0.336898] gpio-148 (scl): enforced open drain please flag it properly in DT/ACPI DSDT/board file
[    0.336905] gpio gpiochip4: Persistence not supported for GPIO 20
[    0.337394] i2c 2-002d: Fixing up cyclic dependency with lvds_panel
[    0.337484] i2c 2-002d: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 32e10000.mipi_dsi
[    0.337687] sn65dsi83 2-002d: GPIO lookup for consumer enable
[    0.337695] sn65dsi83 2-002d: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    0.337717] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'enable-gpios' property of node '/soc@0/bus@30800000/i2c@30a50000/sn65dsi83@2d[0]' - status (0)
[    0.337767] gpio gpiochip3: Persistence not supported for GPIO 19
[    0.338351] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'reset-gpios' property of node '/soc@0/bus@30800000/i2c@30a50000/tlv320aic32x4@18[0]' - status (0)
[    0.338398] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up ldoin-supply from device tree
[    0.338409] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up ldoin-supply property in node /soc@0/bus@30800000/i2c@30a50000/tlv320aic32x4@18 failed
[    0.338446] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up iov-supply from device tree
[    0.338569] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up dv-supply from device tree
[    0.338703] tlv320aic32x4 2-0018: Looking up av-supply from device tree
[    0.349344] i2c i2c-2: IMX I2C adapter registered
[    0.350002] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: maps: function pinctrl group pwm3grp num 2
[    0.350017] pinctrl core: add 2 pinctrl maps
[    0.350047] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: found group selector 0 for pwm3grp
[    0.350097] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: request pin 138 (MX8MM_IOMUXC_I2C3_SDA) for 30680000.pwm
[    0.350107] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: enable function pinctrl group pwm3grp
[    0.350114] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: write: offset 0x228 val 0x1
[    0.350123] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: pinconf set pin MX8MM_IOMUXC_I2C3_SDA
[    0.350130] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: write: offset 0x490 val 0x6
[    0.350462] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: maps: function pinctrl group lcd-engrp num 2
[    0.350473] pinctrl core: add 2 pinctrl maps
[    0.350499] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: found group selector 29 for lcd-engrp
[    0.350514] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: request pin 14 (MX8MM_IOMUXC_GPIO1_IO04) for backlight
[    0.350522] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: enable function pinctrl group lcd-engrp
[    0.350529] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: write: offset 0x38 val 0x0
[    0.350537] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: pinconf set pin MX8MM_IOMUXC_GPIO1_IO04
[    0.350543] imx8mm-pinctrl 30330000.pinctrl: write: offset 0x2a0 val 0x156
[    0.350583] pwm-backlight backlight: GPIO lookup for consumer enable
[    0.350591] pwm-backlight backlight: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    0.350616] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'enable-gpios' property of node '/backlight[0]' - status (0)
[    0.350642] gpio gpiochip0: Persistence not supported for GPIO 4
[    0.350649] gpio-4 (enable): no flags found for enable
[    0.350658] pwm-backlight backlight: Looking up power-supply from device tree
[    0.354066] panel-lvds lvds_panel: Looking up power-supply from device tree
[    0.354219] panel-lvds lvds_panel: GPIO lookup for consumer enable
[    0.354227] panel-lvds lvds_panel: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    0.354240] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'enable-gpios' property of node '/lvds_panel[0]'
[    0.354270] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'enable-gpio' property of node '/lvds_panel[0]' - status (0)
[    0.354293] gpio gpiochip0: Persistence not supported for GPIO 7
[    0.354304] panel-lvds lvds_panel: GPIO lookup for consumer reset
[    0.354310] panel-lvds lvds_panel: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    0.354321] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'reset-gpios' property of node '/lvds_panel[0]'
[    0.354344] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'reset-gpio' property of node '/lvds_panel[0]' - status (0)
[    0.354363] gpio gpiochip0: Persistence not supported for GPIO 9
[    0.355970] imx-drm 32c00000.bus:display-subsystem: bound imx-lcdif-crtc.0 (ops lcdif_crtc_ops)
[    0.356178] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e10000.mipi_dsi: version number is 0x1060200
[    0.356253] [drm:drm_bridge_attach] *ERROR* failed to attach bridge /soc@0/bus@32c00000/mipi_dsi@32e10000 to encoder DSI-34: -517
[    0.368017] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e10000.mipi_dsi: Failed to attach bridge: 32e10000.mipi_dsi
[    0.376296] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e10000.mipi_dsi: failed to bind sec dsim bridge: -517
```

and the part when it tries again with a succesfully loaded sn65dsi83 driver:

```
[    0.608886] sn65dsi83 2-002d: GPIO lookup for consumer enable
[    0.608896] sn65dsi83 2-002d: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    0.608918] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'enable-gpios' property of node '/soc@0/bus@30800000/i2c@30a50000/sn65dsi83@2d[0]' - status (0)
[    0.608970] gpio gpiochip3: Persistence not supported for GPIO 19
[    0.609860] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    0.609870] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 74 at drivers/reset/core.c:765 __reset_control_get_internal+0x68/0x1a0
[    0.609892] Modules linked in:
[    0.609900] CPU: 0 PID: 74 Comm: kworker/u8:2 Not tainted 5.15.32-karo+gc01cf92b4155 #1
[    0.609909] Hardware name: Ka-Ro TX8M-1610 module on GOcontroll Moduline Screen for av123z7m-n17 screen (DT)
[    0.609915] Workqueue: events_unbound deferred_probe_work_func
[    0.609928] pstate: 20000005 (nzCv daif -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[    0.609936] pc : __reset_control_get_internal+0x68/0x1a0
[    0.609945] lr : __of_reset_control_get+0x16c/0x1d0
[    0.609954] sp : ffff80000960b970
[    0.609958] x29: ffff80000960b970 x28: ffff00003fdf5d90 x27: ffff000003c722b8
[    0.609972] x26: 0000000000000001 x25: 0000000000000000 x24: 0000000000000001
[    0.609985] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: ffff000002f60880 x21: 0000000000000005
[    0.609998] x20: ffff000002f608a0 x19: ffff000003cd8580 x18: 0000000000000000
[    0.610012] x17: 65646f6e20666f20 x16: 79747265706f7270 x15: 0000000000000001
[    0.610025] x14: ffffffffffffffff x13: 0000000000000038 x12: 0101010101010101
[    0.610039] x11: 0000000000000028 x10: 0101010101010101 x9 : 0000000000000000
[    0.610052] x8 : 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f x7 : 6f21ff726b6b6462 x6 : 0000000000802370
[    0.610064] x5 : fffffbfffddf963c x4 : 0000000000000000 x3 : 0000000000000001
[    0.610077] x2 : 0000000000000005 x1 : 0000000000000005 x0 : 0000000000000000
[    0.610092] Call trace:
[    0.610095]  __reset_control_get_internal+0x68/0x1a0
[    0.610105]  __of_reset_control_get+0x16c/0x1d0
[    0.610113]  of_reset_control_array_get+0xac/0x24c
[    0.610122]  imx_sec_dsim_probe+0x24c/0x33c
[    0.610131]  platform_probe+0x68/0xe0
[    0.610139]  really_probe+0xbc/0x46c
[    0.610146]  __driver_probe_device+0x114/0x190
[    0.610155]  driver_probe_device+0x40/0x100
[    0.610163]  __device_attach_driver+0x98/0x130
[    0.610171]  bus_for_each_drv+0x78/0xd0
[    0.610178]  __device_attach+0xdc/0x1c0
[    0.610186]  device_initial_probe+0x14/0x20
[    0.610195]  bus_probe_device+0x98/0xa0
[    0.610202]  deferred_probe_work_func+0xac/0x100
[    0.610210]  process_one_work+0x1dc/0x370
[    0.610221]  worker_thread+0x1f0/0x434
[    0.610229]  kthread+0x138/0x150
[    0.610239]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
[    0.610247] ---[ end trace 3012c882e1782c86 ]---
[    0.610284] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    0.610287] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 74 at drivers/reset/core.c:765 __reset_control_get_internal+0x68/0x1a0
[    0.610299] Modules linked in:
[    0.610305] CPU: 0 PID: 74 Comm: kworker/u8:2 Tainted: G        W         5.15.32-karo+gc01cf92b4155 #1
[    0.610312] Hardware name: Ka-Ro TX8M-1610 module on GOcontroll Moduline Screen for av123z7m-n17 screen (DT)
[    0.610317] Workqueue: events_unbound deferred_probe_work_func
[    0.610326] pstate: 20000005 (nzCv daif -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[    0.610334] pc : __reset_control_get_internal+0x68/0x1a0
[    0.610343] lr : __of_reset_control_get+0x16c/0x1d0
[    0.610352] sp : ffff80000960b970
[    0.610356] x29: ffff80000960b970 x28: ffff00003fdf5fb8 x27: ffff000003c722b8
[    0.610370] x26: 0000000000000001 x25: 0000000000000000 x24: 0000000000000001
[    0.610382] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: ffff000002f60a80 x21: 0000000000000009
[    0.610396] x20: ffff000002f60aa0 x19: ffff000003cd8200 x18: 0000000000000000
[    0.610410] x17: 65646f6e20666f20 x16: 79747265706f7270 x15: 0000000000000001
[    0.610422] x14: ffffffffffffffff x13: 0000000000000038 x12: 0101010101010101
[    0.610436] x11: 0000000000000028 x10: 0101010101010101 x9 : 0000000000000000
[    0.610450] x8 : 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f x7 : 6f21ff726b6b6462 x6 : 0000000000802370
[    0.610462] x5 : fffffbfffddf9684 x4 : 0000000000000000 x3 : 0000000000000001
[    0.610475] x2 : 0000000000000009 x1 : 0000000000000009 x0 : 0000000000000000
[    0.610488] Call trace:
[    0.610492]  __reset_control_get_internal+0x68/0x1a0
[    0.610501]  __of_reset_control_get+0x16c/0x1d0
[    0.610510]  of_reset_control_array_get+0xac/0x24c
[    0.610519]  imx_sec_dsim_probe+0x24c/0x33c
[    0.610526]  platform_probe+0x68/0xe0
[    0.610535]  really_probe+0xbc/0x46c
[    0.610542]  __driver_probe_device+0x114/0x190
[    0.610551]  driver_probe_device+0x40/0x100
[    0.610558]  __device_attach_driver+0x98/0x130
[    0.610566]  bus_for_each_drv+0x78/0xd0
[    0.610573]  __device_attach+0xdc/0x1c0
[    0.610581]  device_initial_probe+0x14/0x20
[    0.610589]  bus_probe_device+0x98/0xa0
[    0.610596]  deferred_probe_work_func+0xac/0x100
[    0.610605]  process_one_work+0x1dc/0x370
[    0.610613]  worker_thread+0x1f0/0x434
[    0.610623]  kthread+0x138/0x150
[    0.610630]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
[    0.610637] ---[ end trace 3012c882e1782c87 ]---
[    0.610670] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    0.610673] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 74 at drivers/reset/core.c:765 __reset_control_get_internal+0x68/0x1a0
[    0.610686] Modules linked in:
[    0.610691] CPU: 0 PID: 74 Comm: kworker/u8:2 Tainted: G        W         5.15.32-karo+gc01cf92b4155 #1
[    0.610700] Hardware name: Ka-Ro TX8M-1610 module on GOcontroll Moduline Screen for av123z7m-n17 screen (DT)
[    0.610704] Workqueue: events_unbound deferred_probe_work_func
[    0.610713] pstate: 20000005 (nzCv daif -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[    0.610721] pc : __reset_control_get_internal+0x68/0x1a0
[    0.610731] lr : __of_reset_control_get+0x16c/0x1d0
[    0.610740] sp : ffff80000960b970
[    0.610744] x29: ffff80000960b970 x28: ffff00003fdf61e0 x27: ffff000003c722b8
[    0.610757] x26: 0000000000000001 x25: 0000000000000000 x24: 0000000000000001
[    0.610770] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: ffff000003009480 x21: 0000000000000001
[    0.610783] x20: ffff0000030094a0 x19: ffff000003cd8d80 x18: 0000000000000000
[    0.610797] x17: 65646f6e20666f20 x16: 79747265706f7270 x15: 0000000000000001
[    0.610810] x14: ffffffffffffffff x13: 0000000000000038 x12: 0101010101010101
[    0.610823] x11: 0000000000000028 x10: 0101010101010101 x9 : 0000000000000000
[    0.610837] x8 : 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f x7 : 6f21ff726b6b6462 x6 : 0000000000802370
[    0.610851] x5 : fffffbfffddf96d4 x4 : 0000000000000000 x3 : 0000000000000001
[    0.610863] x2 : 0000000000000001 x1 : 0000000000000001 x0 : 0000000000000000
[    0.610876] Call trace:
[    0.610880]  __reset_control_get_internal+0x68/0x1a0
[    0.610890]  __of_reset_control_get+0x16c/0x1d0
[    0.610898]  of_reset_control_array_get+0xac/0x24c
[    0.610908]  imx_sec_dsim_probe+0x24c/0x33c
[    0.610915]  platform_probe+0x68/0xe0
[    0.610923]  really_probe+0xbc/0x46c
[    0.610931]  __driver_probe_device+0x114/0x190
[    0.610939]  driver_probe_device+0x40/0x100
[    0.610947]  __device_attach_driver+0x98/0x130
[    0.610955]  bus_for_each_drv+0x78/0xd0
[    0.610962]  __device_attach+0xdc/0x1c0
[    0.610970]  device_initial_probe+0x14/0x20
[    0.610978]  bus_probe_device+0x98/0xa0
[    0.610985]  deferred_probe_work_func+0xac/0x100
[    0.610993]  process_one_work+0x1dc/0x370
[    0.611002]  worker_thread+0x1f0/0x434
[    0.611011]  kthread+0x138/0x150
[    0.611019]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
[    0.611026] ---[ end trace 3012c882e1782c88 ]---
[    0.611035] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e10000.mipi_dsi: no invalid reset control exists
[    0.618433] imx_sec_dsim_drv: probe of 32e10000.mipi_dsi failed with error -22
```

I hope somebody cal help me fix the init sequence.

Comment: Did you found the solution to it? Also, how did you setup the sn65dsi83 on the device tree?

Comment: i have unfortunately not found the perfect solution for it, i found a different sn65dsi84 driver on the variscite linux repo : https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/tree/lf-5.10.y_var04/drivers/gpu/drm/bridge/sn65dsi83

they also provide a fix to sec_mipi_dsim-imx.c which fixes the stack traces: https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.15-2.0.x-imx_var01/drivers/gpu/drm/imx/sec_mipi_dsim-imx.c

sadly i didnt manage to get the regular driver working with this fix though. but i did get my sn65dsi84 chip working with the first link

Comment: Can you share your device tree with me. I want to setup the sn65dsi84 bridge with an IMX8MQ processor.

Comment: yeah sure [here it is](https://pastebin.com/7y0C2Qxc) i missed a closing bracket at the end it seems.  I never got the driver that's in the standard kernel working unfortunately

Comment: Thanks, I can't get it to work either after doing so many changes.

Comment: Mine doesn't even work with DCSS, so I have to use LCDIF. The driver for the SN65 doesn't even register.

Comment: are you making sure the driver is in the makefile of the layer below it? So that would be /drivers/gpu/drm/bridge/Makefile. It was definetly a frustrating journey for me to get it to work aswell.

Comment: Yeah, im reading through the source code. I'm still debugging the issue.

Comment: You need to really write the device tree on a very specific way. Also use the DCSS system and on the simple-panel driver look for the correct encoding.